# Icinga2 - check_interval for cluster-zone check

Tags: linux, monitoring, icinga2

I have defined a host template that uses the check_command as cluster_zone. I have set the check_interval to 2m, retry_inteval to 1m and max_check_attempts to 3.

So, I am expecting to get a host down notification after 3m. However, the notification comes in just a few seconds.

How can I increase cluster_zone variables ??

Comment: Can you add your service definition?